# Is memory access slower than shifting?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Which of the following two code snippets would generally run faster (without compiler optimizations)? This code is just an example - I am aware that there are faster ways to do the same calculation.

```cpp
// arr points to the following array: [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
// assume that it has already been created, so that the
// array creation does not cause a time penalty
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    result += arr[i];
}
```

```cpp
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    result += (1 << i);
}
```

I am pretty sure that the memory access would be slower, but I would like some confirmation.

EDIT: in order to clarify this question, I am SPECIFICALLY interested in the un-optimized version of this code. Not because I actually intend to use this code in production, but because I am interested in the concept of whether memory access or arithmetic is faster. Perhaps I should have written the code in assembly language instead of C/C++ in order to further clarify that I am not interested in compiler optimizations of the code.

Some of the responses say that memory access is slower in most cases, while others say that I should benchmark and that it depends on my processor and system.

The architecture of interest is x86 or x86-64 - something that you could find in a modern laptop or desktop computer in 2021. I will edit this question again once I have run some benchmarks on both the unoptimized and optimized versions of this code. Thanks to everyone who has responded so far.

EDIT 2: I ran gprof on a variation of the two code snippets above and found that, on average (after several billion runs), the version of the calculation which uses memory access takes roughly 2.4 nanoseconds while the version which uses arithmetic takes roughly 1.1 nanoseconds. This is on a 64-bit Linux computer.

The runs were unoptimized (-O0) and used GCC version 10.2.0. I also tried using clang version 10.0.1 with the following results: an average of 2.45 nanoseconds for the memory version (not significantly different from GCC) and 1.63 nanoseconds for the arithmetic version (significantly worse than GCC, although this difference may have had other causes ... my benchmark was not rigorous as it was just meant to give a rough estimate).

The variation which I used for benchmarking replaced the loop with a series of 7 repetitive lines of code (`result += arr[0]; ...`, `result += (1 << 0); ...`), since I found that the looping itself took far more time than the calculation in both cases.

I didn't bother with optimized runs as I know that the arithmetic version would be optimized to a single constant (127 or 0x7F) and it's really just a test of whether the compiler is smart enough to optimize the memory version.

Comment: If you want to know if X is faster than Y, use a [benchmarker](https://quick-bench.com/)

Comment: There is no "general" answer to this. Depending on architecture memory access might be faster or slower than arithmetic operations

Comment: On any modern processor (after 1990 or so), it is almost certainly the case that memory access will be much slower than shifting.

Comment: "*...without compiler optimizations*" - who cares about unoptimized code?

Comment: @rustyx I am more concerned with the concept than the actual execution time of these particular snippets.

Comment: And I could well believe that an optimizing compiler could simply see through either of these loops (at least if the array case uses constants) and simply assign the ultimate value. Certainly I would expect that in the shift case.

Comment: @Agent008 So your conceptual question - what is faster - memory access or an arithmetic operation?

Comment: Whitout optimization, IMO, the second version is faster, notice that `arr[i]` is translated to `*(arr + i)`

Comment: This may help: [https://superuser.com/questions/643442/latency-of-cpu-instructions-on-x86-and-x64-processors](https://superuser.com/questions/643442/latency-of-cpu-instructions-on-x86-and-x64-processors)

Comment: So tempting to just recommend `int result = (1 << 8) -1;`, but I'm afraid that does not address the question...

Comment: I also expect the second version to be faster. A shift is one of the fastest instructions a CPU has.

Comment: @EugeneSh. pretty much. I think this question may have already been answered but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: "without compiler optimizations" is not just uninteresting, it is *meaningless*.  At least optimized code can be taken as the best code the compiler knows how to produce, for some particular definition of "best", but who's to say how that differs from code that the same compiler might otherwise produce?.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "without compiler optimizations" isn't meaningless because in this question, I have simplified my actual code into something that is much more readable, but can also be optimized. However, my original code cannot be optimized in the same ways, so analyzing this code with optimizations would not actually help me.

Comment: @Agent008 If your original code cannot be optimized in the same ways then any answer to this question is useless for you. You have to measure both for your combination of problem, compiler, and system to get an answer.

Comment: @DeanJohnson I just want to know if memory access or shifting is faster. According to the answers I've received so far, this depends on the system, so I will benchmark both ways and see which is faster.

Comment: Not enough data about problem. With current problem description of code compiler is able to optimize this to constant expression: https://godbolt.org/z/8jjEPG

Comment: Please edit your question and provide data which will show what are practical calculation you are trying to do, expected output for specific input. Currently it produces constant value and compiler is able to decipher that. Without it I vote to close question "more info is needed".

Comment: Depends on the processor too... If you're on an AVR, most operations take 1 cycle, and memory access take 2 cycles (IIRC), but shifts only work one bit at a time, so for a variable shift amount, you may need to loop, which may then take longer.

Comment: I added real clock cycles difference benchmarked by Agner Fog in his manual for those interested.

Comment: @Agent008 *I am more concerned with the concept than the actual execution time of these particular snippets.*  The concept of "which instruction is faster" is utterly irrelevant on a deeply-pipelined CPU that executes multiple instructions in parallel.  It's the entire sequence of instructions and the context they run in that matter.  In other words, you're wasting your time micro-optimizing your code like this.  Use an optimizing compiler, ***profile your entire application***, and ***then*** address the performance bottlenecks that actual testing and profile identifies.

Comment: It's still a useless comparison and you will not gain much relevant knowledge. `-O0` on gcc is worse than "no optimization" because it often adds numerous repeated loads and stores which would be eliminated on any sane optimization level. If `arr` is a `static const` array, there will probably be no memory access at all. If it's `volatile`, there will be many more accesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the excellent manuals from [Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/), especially the [one related to C++](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf)

> Optimizing for speed is relevant
> when CPU access and memory access are critical time consumers.

In most of modern architectures, shifting (ALU instruction) will be much faster than memory access, quoting the manual:

#### Shift operations (1 clock cycle)

> shift operations take only one clock cycle on most microprocessors

#### Memory Access (2 to 4 clock cycles, or worse)

> Accessing data from RAM memory can take quite a long time compared to the time it takes
> to do calculations on the data. This is the reason why all modern computers have memory
> caches. Typically, there is a level-1 data cache of 8 - 64 Kbytes and a level-2 cache of 256
> Kbytes to 2 Mbytes. Often, there is also a level-3 cache of several Mbytes.

> the combined size of all data in a program is bigger than the level-2 cache and the data
> are scattered around in memory or accessed in a non-sequential manner then it is likely that
> memory access is the biggest time-consumer in the program. **Reading or writing to a
> variable in memory takes only 2-4 clock cycles if it is cached**, but several hundred clock
> cycles if it is not cached. See page 25 about data storage and page 89 about memory
> caching.

So in your specific example you should go for shifting.

Comment: *Optimizing for speed is relevant when CPU access and memory access are **critical time consumers***  NB the bolded part.  Until you have profiled your application and actually identified the performance bottlenecks, you are almost certainly wasting your time trying to "eyeball optimize" code.  First, what you think looks faster is completely irrelevant to what an optimizing compiler will turn into faster-running instructions.  Second, you are almost certainly ***wrong*** in what needs to be optimized.  If you haven't profiled your application, you haven't identified the **critical** parts.

Comment: You make a very good point but I assume that this question was asked precisely because it is critical. There are 3 kind of people: Those who faithfully trust (like it is some kind of religion) the compiler to optimize, those who simply don't care about the performance, and those who actively look to optimize before the compiler. Fortunately Agner Fog did a fantastic job by synthesizing most of this stuff for us mortals, and I will always be very thankful for his insights.

Answer (score 1):

Inasmuch as your question seems to be about the relative speed of loading a word from memory *vs*. performing an arithmetic operation, you seem really to be asking for a comparison more like the evaluation of

```
*p
```

*vs*. that of

```
p + 1
```

, where `p` is a pointer to `int` whose value does not itself need to be fetched from memory (because it's already in a CPU register).  Generally speaking, the arithmetic units of modern CPUs run at least several times faster than the attached memory subsystems, even for memory locations whose contents are currently available from the CPU's fastest cache, so one would ordinarily expect the latter to be faster.

But it really doesn't make sense to look at performance questions with this granularity, and especially not to ask about unoptimized code.  The performance of a whole program that includes operations such as these is greatly affected by the context of the operations, and if you're seeking the best performance then you will of course compile *with* optimizations, not without.  Moreover, it is altogether unclear in general how code produced without optimization enabled will differ from code produced with optimization enabled, if it differs at all in any given case.

Overall, the question has a strong smell of premature optimization -- that is, programmer micro-optimization, not compiler optimization -- and this is generally counterproductive. For best performance, use the best algorithms for the problem, and write clean, natural code.  This will often help the compiler do a better job at optimizing, and it will definitely make your code easier to debug and maintain.  If the resulting program is not fast enough then *profile* it to determine where the biggest bottlenecks are, and work on those.

Answer (score 1):

Including [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) into the comparison would also be interesting.  It uses something referred to in the article as [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) to reduce the instructions necessary to copy by reducing the number of loops.

> *"The basic idea of loop unrolling is that the number of instructions executed in a loop can be reduced by reducing the number
> of loop tests, sometimes reducing the amount of time spent in the
> loop. For example, in the case of a loop with only a single
> instruction in the block code, the loop test will typically be
> performed for every iteration of the loop, that is every time the
> instruction is executed. If, instead, eight copies of the same
> instruction are placed in the loop, then the test will be performed
> only every eight iterations, and this may gain time by avoiding seven
> tests. However, this only handles a multiple of eight iterations,
> requiring something else to handle any remainder of iterations."*

Example code snippet of Duff's Device:

```
void copy_duff(register short *to, register short *from, register  count)
{
    register n=(count+7)/8;
    switch(count%8) {
        case 0:    do {    *to = *from++;
        case 7:        *to = *from++;
        case 6:        *to = *from++;
        case 5:        *to = *from++;
        case 4:        *to = *from++;
        case 3:        *to = *from++;
        case 2:        *to = *from++;
        case 1:        *to = *from++;
        } while(--n>0);
    }
}
```